# Non-interactive customization and installation of FreeBSD Ports

Tags: freebsd

I'm new to FreeBSD, coming from a Linux background. I want to install a port, changing one of the default configuration options, in a non-interactive way (so that I can script the installation for automated configuration of my FreeBSD servers).

As a specific example, the `graphics/ImageMagick-nox11` port has a default configuration option of `PERL=on`. I want to change this. I realize that I can `make config` and then just use the generated entry in `/var/db/ports/` to avoid any interaction in the future, but this still requires the initial interaction to set the options in the ncurses interface.

Ideally I want to be able to do something like the following, to build the package with perl support disabled but accepting all other defaults:

```
$ make PERL=off BATCH=yes install clean
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this? Can I somehow place port-specific configuration options like this in `/etc/make.conf`?

Comment: Relevant http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5257/3226

Comment: belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can also unset `OPTIONS` via make.conf(5).

E.g.:

```
OPTIONS_UNSET=NLS
```